# Script to change folder creation dates, taken from folder names

Tags: powershell

I need help creating a script in Powershell. I would be grateful for your help in this matter.

I have directories whose names contain the correct creation dates.
E.g. '2022-07-01', '2022-07-14', '2022-08-01' etc.

I would like to change the creation dates of these directories to those in their names.

I've tried using Get-Item, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use this function for the full range of data

Comment: "whose names contain" ... is the date string the only such sequence in the folder name? Or could you encounter one like `folder-2022-07-01-photos-from-2021-03-16`?

Answer (score 2):

This will use the last date specified in the filename to set the `CreationTime` property of the file. You might want to change the `LastWriteTime` since that is what appears when using `Get-ChildItem`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Item {
    if ($_.Name -match '^.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*') {
        $_.CreationTime = [datetime]$Matches[1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following process all subdirectories in a given directory and, for directory names that can be parsed as dates, sets the creation date (`.CreationTime` property) of the directory at hand to that date (expressed in local time):

```bash
$dir = '.' # adjust as needed
Get-ChildItem -Directory -LiteralPath $dir |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($date = $_.Name -as [datetime]) { # Can the name be interpreted as a date?
      $_.CreationTime = $date
    }
  }
```

If you want to process the input dir. *recursively*, i.e. to process all directories in the entire *subtree*, add `-Recurse` to the `Get-ChildItem` call.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your help.
I modified the  example I found and it worked.

```
$folders = Get-Item *
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    Get-Item -Path $folder.Name | Foreach-Object {$_.CreationTime=($folder.Name)}
}
```

Comment: `Get-Item *` doesn't limit the results to _folders_ (directories). Aside from that, there is no need for `Get-Item -Path $folder.Name` - just use `$folder`. Given that `$folder` is by definition a _single_ folder, you don't need a `ForEach-Object` call - just use `$folder.CreationTime = $folder.Name`.